# Multiple Apache Artemis destinations vs a single destination

Tags: messaging, activemq-artemis

I am not sure what's the best approach, I have 10K users and each subscribes to 5 topics for a total of 50K topics, or I can change it so that each user subscribe to one topic for a total of 10K topics and use a payloadType attribute to differentiate the type of message. Basically, 10K topics with alot of message flow vs 50K topics with small message flow. Which is more salable and overall a better approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, if you're using the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis message broker and you've configured a JMS topic (in versions < 2.x) or a multicast address (in 2.x) and you have 10K subscribers then in either case you'll end up with 50K *queues* (which represent the subscriptions).  Or if you have 1 topic/address and 10K subscribers then you'll end up with 10K *queues*.

If you go with 10K queues and use a payloadType to differentiate the type of message then I believe your clients will have to filter through a lot of messages that they don't actually want which also means the broker will be dispatching lots of messages which are ultimately useless.  This approach is less scalable than the alternative where each subscriber is only getting the messages it really cares about.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the advise.